# Failed to host a static website on AWS s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created my portfolio website, so now I would like to upload it on AWS s3.
I bought a custom domain name for it, but before using it, I can't even host my website with the endpoint URL (something like this: http://masahiro-takechi.com.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com). When I copied and pasted it on Google, it says "This page isn't working".
[image]

I believe I set proper settings to be able to host the website such as permissions and Static website hosting, and so on. Permissions are totally public, unblock access, generate correct bucket policy, and upload right folders and files like index.html.
[image]

[image]

[image]

All tips would help me greatly, thanks for your time to help me in advance!!;)

Comment: Your bucket has different name then your link. How come?

Comment: Oh, my bucket name is masahiro-takechi.com and engineer_portfolio_resume is a folder that I created on VS Code. I don't think so, but do you think I need to delete that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your website should be in a **root folder** of the bucket. Otherwise, you have to access it using your folder:

> http://masahiro-takechi.com.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/engineer_portfolio_resume/index.html

Comment: Thanks so much!! it works now and I can start trying to link the website and a domain name I got from Namecheap!!